# Vista can create partitions but can't install?

Tags: windows-vista, partitioning, drivers, ssd

I'm trying to install Vista on a brand new SSD. As soon as I get to the screen where you can make partitions, it tells me that it can't install to the selected location "Error 0x80300001". Some quick googling revealed that 0x8030001 = sata drivers are missing. But I don't get it. How is it that it can see the disk, create, delete, and format partitions, and yet is unable to install there?

I even went out and got the SATA drivers for machine (like five different versions), loaded them all, same problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: Question:  If the SSD is blank because you can not install Vista what do you mean by installed all versions of the driver?

Comment: Ok, not "install"; I used the "Load Driver" option in that window. I loaded all these different driver versions. Excuse my misnomer.

Comment: Usually that means the drivers don't match the hardware.  Did you go to the motherboards manufacturer website and get the drivers from there?

Comment: Yessir. No dice. I just put the drive in a different machine, installed it, and moved it back... Gotta love workarounds.